# Google Glass: refocusing to a live card

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to have a live card come back to view after some event? What I'm doing right now is unpublishing the card and then publishing it again and that works when the card is off screen. The problem is since there's no way to check whether the card is currently visible, it causes the home screen to flicker into view and the click sound to happen twice if the card is currently displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't yet an API to navigate to an existing live card in the timeline. Please feel free to file a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) so that you can track the feature as the GDK evolves!